# Sedimentation at the bottom of a vessel

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

At the moment I'm studying the sedimentation of suspensions.
There is a lot of literature discussing the physics behind this processes (e.g., [1](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=394601&fulltextType=RA&fileId=S0022112088002630), [2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0301932282900647), [3](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1952/TF/tf9524800166#!divAbstract), [4](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aic.690270517/abstract)).

Most of the sources I found  study only the behaviour near the top of the vessel (i.e, they ignore the bottom boundary of the vessel).
By now I have a rather good understanding of these theories.

But really the bottom is where all the fun happens (e.g., maximum packing density). The most recent source I found is [this book from 1994](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122824709).

Question(s):

**Is there a (nice) book/article which discusses the (state of art) physics of sedimentation near the bottom of a vessel (for mono-disperse solutions)?**

**Also, what about poly-disperse solutions?**

For a first shot all simplifying assumptions are fine (low Reynolds number,...).

Comment: Did you look into the field of fluidized beds? I can imagine there are relevant similarities.